# ChangeListener functionality to check typed value with time delay / or other solution

Tags: java, javafx

I am looking for functionality in my code to allow me few seconds to type full
name in simpleTextField, I need it because if I type for example:

1. I type R - then method changed is doing it's task
2. I type RR - then method changed does same thing twice (which I don't want)

So what would be the best way to allow program wait few seconds so it gives me time to fully type required value, then method will be executed only once

```
    simpleTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

       // some funtionality to do

     }
```

Comment: What value are you trying to type? Maybe you need to do things based on the length of the `String` and then check the value?

Comment: it's a bit more complicated, I have car rental company app and methods checks if car can be booked for some specific days based on VIN number (comparing with current reservations). Problem is if I type VIN starting with A.... then AB.... both VIN numbers are being taken under this comparing process

Comment: Aren't VIN Number a cetrain length? If so, wait until the length is meet, then check the number.\

Comment: hmm, yep this might be the case

Comment: VIN number has always 17 characters

Comment: it will solve my issue, do you know how can I implement that?

Comment: `if(newValue.length() == 17){//do something};`

Comment: of course, couldn't be simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `PauseTransition` that gets played from start every time the `text` property of the `TextField` is modified.

The following code adds the content of the `TextField` to a `ListView` 1 sec after the last modification to the `TextField.text` is done:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextField text = new TextField();

    ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();

    PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
    delay.setOnFinished(evt -> {
        list.getItems().add(text.getText());
    });

    // restart delay every time the text is modified
    text.textProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> delay.playFromStart());

    VBox root = new VBox(text, list);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

You may want to add another listener to the `anchor` property to also handle changes of the selection.